# Pasting Worksheets Data from each sheet in One column - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i have code:

```
    Dim wksSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wksDst As Worksheet
    Dim rgSrc As Range
    Dim rgDst As Range
    Dim lrgRow As Long
    Dim lrgSrcRow As Long
    
    
    Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CheckP")
    lrgRow = wksDst.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    
    Set rgDst = wksDst.Cells(lrgRow, 1)
    
    For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
         If wksSrc.Name <> "Config" And wksSrc.Name <> "Summary" And wksSrc.Name <> "CheckP" Then
            lrgSrcRow = wksSrc.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row
            With wksSrc
                wksSrc.Range("A2:B" & wksSrc.Cells(wksSrc.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row).Copy Destination:=rgDst
            End With
            
            lrgRow = wksDst.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
            Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lrgRow + 1, 1)
            
        End If
        
    Next wksSrc

End Sub
```

**1**. **I do not understand why the data that is copied in the file do not paste under the new last cell, but overwrite.** like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM1jl.png)

The purpose of the code is:

From each worksheet other than Summary, Config and CheckP copied columns A and B and pasted them to the CheckP worksheet as an aggregate column

Could someone please help me improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need to set the destination range each time, you already define a destination reference in lrgRow. You can try to replace the destination as per below

```
Dim wksSrc As Worksheet
Dim wksDst As Worksheet
Dim rgSrc As Range
Dim rgDst As Range
Dim lrgRow As Long
Dim lrgSrcRow As Long


Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CheckP")
lrgRow = wksDst.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rgDst = wksDst.Cells(lrgRow, 1)


For Each wksSrc In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     If wksSrc.Name <> "Config" And wksSrc.Name <> "Summary" And wksSrc.Name <> "CheckP" Then
        lrgSrcRow = wksSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        With wksSrc
            wksSrc.Range("A2:B" & lrgSrcRow).Copy Destination:=wksDst.Range("A" & lrgRow)
        End With
        
        lrgRow = wksDst.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDst = wksDst.Cells(lrgRow + 1, 1)
        
    End If
    
Next wksSrc
```